# DeclareMathOperator with capital Greek letter

Tags: luatex, math-operators, amsthm, greek

So, I tried to do something like this

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\hs}{\Theta}
```

and I was quite surprised to find out, that this does not work (i.e., writing `$\hs$` yields no output but no error message as well).

After a little testing I found that this is the case for all capital Greek letters, e.g. `\DeclareMathOperator{\hs}{\lambda}` works correctly and `\hs` gets compiled to a small lambda, while with `\DeclareMathOperator{\hs}{\Lambda}`  the command `\hs` does not generate any output after compilation.

I worked my way through the documentation of [amsopn](ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsopn.pdf), and I found in the
definition of `\DeclareMathOperator` that the problem lies within the `\operator@font` command defined as

```
\def\operator@font{\mathgroup\symoperators}.
```

It seems that the problem lies within the `\mathgroup` macro. Sadly, I haven't found anything, which explains why something like `\mathgroup\symoperators\Gamma` does not work. And before I waste an entire day on this I rather ask you guys. Thanks in advance.

### EDIT

I'm using LuaLaTex.

Comment: The snippet works fine for me. A full MWE may be helpful.

Comment: No problems here either. So as campa says, please provide something where we do not have to guess most of the document

Comment: Yes, I should have created a MWE, this basically answered my own question.. It's probably the best, if we delete the question?

Comment: I think there is no need to delete the question, but you should definitely update it (and your answer) as to make clear what the problem is (and what solution worked).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was the `\operator@font` command and the usage of LuaLaTeX without `unicode-math`. Including the package provided the necessary glyph.

Apparently, the small Greek letters aren't changed by `\operator@font`, while the capital letters are. Therefore this problem emerged.

Comment: this isn't really an answer other than a hint that your math definitions do not match the fonts you are using. in the classic 7 bit TeX math font encodings the upper case Greek is in the roman font, and the lowercase greek is in the math italic. however none of that is built in to tex, if you are using fonts with different encodings you need to redefine \Theta to match.